# Click package validator is missing from Ubuntu SDK!

Tags: application-development, click-packages

I can't see an option to validate click packages in ubuntu-sdk. Am I missing something?

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04
ubuntu-sdk version : `1.126`
qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu version : `3.0.1+14.10.20140521.1-0ubuntu1~0trusty1`
qtcreator version : `3.0.1-0ubuntu4`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install `click-reviewers-tools` from the Ubuntu SDK PPA. `qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu` currently only suggests that package, it does not depend on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, you will need to ensure that you have the Ubuntu SDK PPA installed on your system. If you do not have the PPA, you can install it by running the following command in the terminal,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

When you open your project in Qtcreator and navigate to the publish tab, you should see something like,

[image]

You can either choose to create a new click package which will automatically check the validity of the click package. You could also validate any other click packages you might have in your system by pressing the validate click package button which should show a file picker dialog where you can choose your click package.

Comment: I followed your answer, but still validating is not available. My *ubuntu-sdk* version is `1.126` and *qtcreator* version is `3.0.1-0ubuntu4`

Comment: Can I validate the package from command line?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install click-reviewers-tools.

```
sudo apt-get install click-reviewers-tools
```